# What is the difference between File Type and File Format?

Tags: pdf, file-format, documents, filetype

I've some confusion regarding the File Type and File Format.
Is it  that Document is a File Type and PDF a file format?
or Video is a File Type and MP4 is a file format ?

Comment: A text file can be considered a file type but there as many ways to *format* that data. Even if it's plain text it may have additional encoding. ASCII. UCS-2. UTF-32. There is an enormous number of encoding types for just text alone.

Answer (score 2):

file type is the extension of a file. e.g `.pdf`, `.mp4`, `.exe` etc.

file format is more of a data structure of a certain file type:

> A [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format) defines the syntax (permitted values, formal
> structure/"grammar") and semantics (meaning and interpretation) of
> data within a file. It thus represents a bidirectional mapping of
> information onto a one-dimensional binary memory.

Knowing the file format is essential for interpreting the information stored in a file. Modern operating systems use the file format to assign files to applications that can interpret the files.

e.g mp4 is one of many video file formats but it's the only mp4 file type. because file type is just the extension. video file format would be more of an umbrella term for all the file formats that represent videos. there are multiple video file formats with different file types (extensions) which all can be summarised as video file format. [read it more detailed on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format)

but yes, if someone would ask you: "What file format is the .mp4 file type?" you could answer: "it's a video file format".

Comment: so if Mp4 is a  FileType, then would "Video" would be called File Fomat ?

Comment: @kevv somewhat yes and somewhat no. read my edit

Comment: To add to this awesome answer.. it is confusing and you will find that different people use different terminology.  I like his comment about the "umbrella term".. good examples of this are ALSO zip, wav, and tiff.. in these types of files, the only similarity would be the beginning of the file which describes its contents (called a header) so a program knows how to unravel them.

Comment: The two terms are misused interchangeably but this is generally understood. Sometimes different extensions can even mean the same thing like .tif vs .tiff, .jpg vs .jpeg, .mpg vs .mpeg, etc. Knowing the file extension is less important than knowing the actual format. Using a dot-extension is a classic paradigm from old DOS and Windows. Many operating systems and some applications may ignore the extension entirely and use metadata, file headers, or a magic number within the first few bytes to determine the file format.

Comment: in the following mime-type or content-type of some files, are the parts before the "/"  File-Format and after the "/"  File-Type ?

application/pdf ,
 video/mp4 ,
 audio/wav ,
 application/x-dosexec ,
 image/jpeg

Comment: @kevv yes they are file-format/file-type

Comment: @SimonS, ok thanks. So lastly we can say File-Type is a subset of File-Format. right ?